# X3DOM Text-Node in 3D Graph rendered as black box after browserupdate

Tags: d3.js, cross-browser, x3dom

I implemented something based on http://bl.ocks.org/hlvoorhees/5986172#index.html. After the latest browserupdates I realized that the textnodes in my Application as well as the ones in the example are now rendered as black boxes (one week ago they looked just fine).

[image: X3Dom D3 scatter plot]

The label creating code is (from the example above)

```
var tickLabels = ticks.selectAll("billboard shape text")
  .data(function(d) { return [d]; });
var newTickLabels = tickLabels.enter()
  .append("billboard")
     .attr("axisOfRotation", "0 0 0")     
  .append("shape")
  .call(makeSolid)
newTickLabels.append("text")
  .attr("string", scale.tickFormat(10))
  .attr("solid", "true")
  .append("fontstyle")
    .attr("size", tickFontSize)
    .attr("family", "SANS")
    .attr("justify", "END MIDDLE" );
tickLabels // enter + update
  .attr("string", scale.tickFormat(10))
tickLabels.exit().remove();
```

The X3DOM-Logdiv doesn't contain any errors or warnings. So I don't know if X3DOM is breaking things or D3, but as it's actually a X3DOM-Node I would locate the problem there.. Neither X3Dom nor D3 updated their libraries lately - however I tried out older versions, but still broken text.

Tested on

- Chromium Version 45.0.2454.101 Ubuntu
- Firefox 42.0
- some current safari (can't tell exactly, sorry)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue while i was trying to get smooth text rendering using big font sizes and a transform to scale them down again. I worked arround the black rectangles by using a small font size and the `quality` attribute and no transform arround it.
For you it could look like like this:

```
.append("fontstyle")
    .attr("size", 0.5)
    .attr("quality","10")
    .attr("family", "SANS")
    .attr("justify", "END MIDDLE" );
```

The `quality` attribute is used for oversampling, so you get nice text rendering even if your text nodes are rather small: http://doc.x3dom.org/author/Text/FontStyle.html

I'm not sure if this is a x3dom bug or if this is intended behaviour for text nodes, which are too small.